# view getting hid behind other view in android activity

Tags: android, image, view, android-viewpager

I am trying to load images in full screen and put two button bars(one at top and one at bottom). But when I test the app, top bar is getting hid by the full image while bottom bar is displayed properly.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relshare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#60000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/set_wallpaper"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/share"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="100000" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relshare2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#60000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bfavorite"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/download"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/download"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reportissue"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/report_issue"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me solve this error

Comment: Try using `FrameLayout` as root layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="100000" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relshare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#60000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/set_wallpaper"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/setaswallpaper"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/share"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relshare2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#60000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bfavorite"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/download"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/download"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reportissue"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/report_issue"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Re-ordering the XML always helps with this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. Can you pls explain the logic behind this?

Comment: The reason is because your viewpager came after your status bar. In android view refreshing, it does so in the order of your XML. Further explanation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing :) I'm glad it help! Please mark it as correct if so :)

Comment: I already tried accepting this post as answer but SO tells me to wait to 5 minutes before accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add following properties to your ViewPager.

```
android:layout_below="@id/relshare"
android:layout_above="@id/relshare2"
```

Of course, you have to move relshare2 declaration above ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but actually I want the image to cover the full screen

Comment: Ok, then only move the relshare declaration below the ViewPager in xml file.